# creating c++ classes that use operators

Tags: c++, class, operators

so basically I'm just sand boxing around with c++ because I'm trying to learn some but when I created a class I quickly found out that using `classType className=value;` will create the class using an overloaded constructor

how do I make it so my class can use other operators like *, == or ||

like i know in python you create private methods like `__plus__` is it something similiar in c++?

Comment: google "c++ operator overloading"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload a lot of operators in C++. In your case you just have to declare functions with the name `operator*`, `operator==` and `operator||` respectively. Some operators might need to be overloaded as member functions of the class, other as free functions.

Here's some function signature examples:

```
X operator*(const X&, const X&);
bool operator==(const X&, const X&);
bool operator||(const X&, const X&);
```

You can [easily find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators) a complete list of overloadable operators on Wikipedia.

Before going into this topic, I suggest you to pick [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) and learn a little bit more of C++. Some operators might be dangerous to overload without the proper precautions and some [might not behave the way you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439979/creating-c-classes-that-use-operators/19440002?noredirect=1#comment28823505_19440002) once overloaded.

Comment: The poster should know that overloaded `operator||` does not act like the normal `||`.  It does not short-circuit.  Both arguments are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Look up overloading operators.

Here are some links that you can use.

http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/
[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

The first two are about how to do it, the third is on why/when.